# Existence of a Hölder homeomorphism satisfying prescribed norm constraints

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, homeomorphism

Let $\Omega$ be a convex body$^{\boldsymbol{1}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.  Fix a positive integer $k$ and some $0<\alpha\leq 1$.  Let $k_1> k_2>0$. Does there necessarily exist a diffeomorphism $\phi^{k,\alpha}\in C(\Omega,\Omega)$ satisfying:
$$
\lVert\phi-1_{\Omega}\rVert_{k,\alpha}= k_1 \text{ and } \lVert\phi-1_{\Omega}\rVert_{\infty}\leq k_2,
$$
where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{k,\alpha}$ is the [usual norm on the Hölder space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition#H%C3%B6lder_spaces) $C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$ is the familiar [sup-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) on $C(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Intuitively, I imagine this can be constructed by starting with some “small homeomorphism” $\tilde{\phi}:\Omega\rightarrow \Omega$ and then smoothing it out/mollifying it.  But I don't know how to formalize this idea, or if it is even true.

**Edit$^{\boldsymbol{1}}$:**
Following *@Pietro Majer*'s point; I should mention that I also assume that $\Omega$ is a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (so non-empty interior) and that $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ *(so $\Omega$ cannot be a point).*

Comment: There is something missing in the question or in my understanding: if $1_\Omega$ is the identity, then $\phi = 1_\Omega$ would do.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner You're right.  I meant to have an equality $\|\phi-1_{\Omega}\|_{k,\alpha}=k_1$ and not an inequality (or else, the problem becomes trivial as you noted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is the answer is no, by the following counter-example
$$.$$

Comment: (sorry I couldn’t resist)

Comment: Is the counterexample a point?

Comment: Oh hahah!  It took me a second, ok.. But what is $\Omega$ is say a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n>0$.  Is it still obvious

Comment: For a convex body, I would take the flow of a sufficiently large(1) smooth field with sufficiently small(2) support in the interior of $\Omega$.  The flow $\eta^t$ at time $t$ is a one parameter family of diffeos $\Omega\to\Omega$, that vary continuously wrto $t$, from $\eta^0=Id$ to a distance (in the chosen norm) larger than $k_1$ by (1), yet less than $k_2$ in uniform norm by (2). By continuity some $t$ should do.

Comment: @PietroMajer That's a great idea, thanks :)